# If f(n) = O(h(n)) then c*f(n) = O(h(n)) for all c > 0 - proof challenged?

Tags: time-complexity

I have been asked to prove or disprove the following conjecture:

For any given constant c>0 | If f(n) = O(h(n)) then c*f(n) = O(h(n))

I have came up with the following counter example:

Let f(n) = n and c = n+1. Then c*f(n) = (n+1)n = n^2+n = O(n^2),

while f(n) = n = O(n)

Therefore, the conjecture is not true because O(n^2) != O(n) when f(n) = n and c = n+1.

Now, I have came upon the following theorem:

> Theorem: Any constant value is is O(1).
>
> Aside: You will often hear a constant running time algorithm described
> as O(1).
>
> Corollary: Given f(x) which is O(g(x)) and a constant a, we
> know that af(x) is O(g(x)).
>
> That is, if we have a function multiplied by a constant, we can ignore
> the constant in the big-O.

Why is that the case, and why am I wrong?

Comment: Your c is not a constant.

Comment: This is trivial.  Just use the definition of O.  Just change the constant from f(n) = O(h(n)) (call it M) to c*M for c*f(n) = O(h(n)).  Your counter example is wrong.  "c*f(n) = (n+1)n" is not true.  c*f(n) = c*n, not (n+1)*n.  c has to be a constant, not a function of n.  "for all c > 0" doesn't mean for all positive functions of n.

Comment: This seems more like math than programming.

Comment: @Takendark, it's algorithm something or other, which I guess is programming.  It's typically taught in second semester (freshman level) intro to algorithm for CS majors.

Comment: @thang Yup, which is exactly where I am at right now. Thank you for your reply. I would have accepted it if you posted it as an answer and not a response. In any case, I will know never to make the same mistake again.

Comment: @thang How many people are going to encounter a programming problem and then stumble upon this question which will give the answer to their problem? My guess is next to none which means it doesn't belong here. There is a math exchange site for things like this.

Comment: @Takendarkk, quite contrary.  A good algorithm analysis background is useful for many programming tasks.  For example, should you try to optimize bubble sort by converting it to assembly language (reducing the c)?  or should you use quicksort?  Also, these are the kind of questions companies ask at interviews for new jr hires.  Also, have you seen the math se (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149990/show-that-if-the-shape-operator-s-lambda-ric-leftrightarrow-the-metric-has-c)?  Look at the kind of questions there!  It's way over most SO user's head (math-wise, not programming wise).

Comment: @thang I will just have to disagree. When the question involves a "proof" it becomes purely math for me. Algorithms may be used in programming, but this site is not about abstract algorithmic analysis imo. People should come here to solve programming problems, not pass interviews.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computer science and not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not thinking of this at large enough scale:

If you have a variable, *n* multiplied by a constant *k* and *n* is growing, the effect of *k* is minimised. And it becomes a limit problem, from grade school calculus.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. Thank you. And I am currently taking calculus I as an undergrad student.

Comment: @GilDekel Ah.. you should be able to understand my answer intuitively though, no?

Comment: Oh, I understood it perfectly. It was a perfectly timed reference to what I currently study at calculus I. In addition with what was mentioned in the other comments (that c must be a constant and not variable dependent), I now understand it more than just intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

`c` is a constant, `n` is a variable thus `n+1` is not a constant